# Installing a SSD, should I or should I not disconnect the battery (MacBook Pro)?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, battery

I'm about to switch my hard drive for an SSD. I checked for instructions online and found tutorials that instruct to disconnect the battery as a first step but I also found some forum posts from people saying it fried their logic board. 
A person also said a genius said disconnecting the battery could fry a logic board.

The mac I want to install the SSD into is a *MacBook Pro 13" late 2011*.

Should I disconnect the battery ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

**You don't need to disconnect the battery, but it's a good idea.**

The only reason you disconnect they battery is to ensure that there is no power on any of the circuits which could inadvertently be shorted.

If people fry their logic board while disconnecting the battery, it's most likely they used a metallic tool (like a screw driver) to pry up the battery connector; use a plastic [spudger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spudger) tool.

[image]

Comment: That's what I thought but the user reporting the genius' statement and that his logic was fried says he used a plastic spudger. Of course we can't know for use. If I only touch the hard drive and SSD is it dangerous not to disconnect the battery ?

Comment: He didn't short it with a plastic spudger, he shorted it with something else. 
 I've changed many drives and upgraded tons of RAM without once disconnecting the battery.  Remove any jewelry, watches, etc. - that's the only thing I can see that could cause an issue.

Comment: So I can change the hard drive to a SSD with no need to disconnect the battery ?

Comment: I also bought a anti static wrist wrap that has a crocodile clip on at its end, should I clip it to the inside of the MacBook Pro aluminum frame once it's opened ? How can I be sure to not discharge any static electricity to the components ? Does the "touch any part of the frame inside the computer" technique also offer an extra precaution ?  Thanks !

Comment: I wonder if spudgers made of cheap plastic are capable of picking up a large static charge? Best to touch *all* tools to ground before using.